# FullCalendar Drupal 7 - Calendar wont Display event over multiple days

Tags: fullcalendar, drupal-7

I am setting up a vacation request calendar and got it posting days that vacation it taken, but it wont stretch the event over multiple days, so if i make a event that goes from the 1st of july to the 5th of july, it will only display the event on the 1st.

I'm using the latest version of the FullCalendar plugin and Library and Drupal 7 with the Bartik theme